# Combining dropdown menu to its button in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I'm wondering how you can get a dropdown menu to blend in with the button clicked as seen in the above image. I've created a flat button with no border to mimic the look of the Edit, View, Project, etc. buttons, and have added a ContextMenuStrip to act as a dropdown whenever one of the buttons is clicked. The image below is however the best I could make it.

[image]

Is it perhaps some tool other than a Button + ContextMenuStrip that needs to be used to achieve a blending look like the first image? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to mimic [main menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu)? Why?

Comment: I was unaware of its existence. Another painfully simple solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MenuStrip control:

[image]

Comment: So simple and disappointing I failed to find that. Thank you